# HTML 5 with salesforce

Tags: html, salesforce, apex-code

I an new to HTML 5. I want to use HTML 5 in salesforce. I wanted to see how salesforec supports HTML5.

Do any body know how to use. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 3):

You can set the HTML5 DOCTYPE in Visualforce pages as of API v23, I believe. This will cause the HTML5 Doctype to used in the generation of your Visualforce page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Assuming that you have a Static Resource called "Movies" with two video files in it, here is a possible way to leverage HTML5 within Visualforce to display video using the native HTML5 video component:

```
  <apex:page docType="html-5.0">
       <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
           <source src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Movies,'movie.mp4')}" type="video/mp4" />
           <source src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Movies,'movie.ogg')}" type="video/ogg" />
           Your browser does not support the video tag.
       </video>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: So, is there a way to send parameter inside apex:page? I have dynamic link for video...

Comment: Actually, no matter how I try, it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague and needs to be more specific. However, in general terms Salesforce.com is more concerned with browser support. Which it currently supports IE7+, and latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. There isn't a concept of HTML5 support as that is more of a question for the browser than the application.

As a best practice for standard visual force development to add functionality to the site you shouldn't be concerned with HTML5 or not. You should focus on using the native components provided so that browser support is inherited.

If you are writing a custom site using the sites technology you can specify a  doctype as an attribute of the apex:page tag. But beyond that you are on your own to develop the site in a way that is supported by the browsers your users are using.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use salesforce! If there is any option not to, don't do it!